# How to find the Laplace transform of $\sin^2 (2t)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

How to find the Laplace transform of $\sin^2 (2t)$?

So far I have: $\sin^2(x) = \frac12 - \frac12 \cos(2x)$.

Comment: Convert the squared sine terminto a sum of cosine and sine terms using trig identities then use tables.

Comment: please provide steps .

Comment: You first - see how it goes.

Comment: sin^2(x) = 1/2 - 1/2 cos(2x)

Comment: Yes, now look up L(1) and $L(cos(2x))$ and remember that L is linear.

Comment: L(1) = 1/s and L(cos(2x))=s/(s^2 + 2^2)

Comment: so it becomes 1/s + 1/2[s/(s^2 + 2^2)]. right . what would be next step ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19347/discussion-between-arpit-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chat defeated me! You are pretty much finished

$$sin^2(2t) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}cos(4t)$$

Transforming
$$L(sin^2(2t)) = \frac{1}{2}L(1) - \frac{1}{2}L(cos(4t))=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{s}) - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{s}{s^2+16})$$

Your x seems to have become a 2t since yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using this theorem,

$
If,L(x(t))=X(s)
\\
L(\frac{d(x(t))}{dt})=sX(s)-x(0^{-})\\\\
Let,
x(t)=sin^{2}(wt)\\
So,
\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=wsin(2wt)\\\\
If, L(sin(2wt))=\frac{2w}{4w^{2}+s^{2}}\\
Hence, L(sin^{2}(wt))=\frac{2w^{2}}{s(s^{2}+4w^{2})}
$